# How to add a condition in a select query?

Tags: sql, oracle

if the condition is true then I want this SQL

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100'
UNION
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
```

if the condition is false then I want this SQL

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
```

I made this query but it didn't work

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0 THEN
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100'
UNION
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
END IF
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD = '1110'
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really odd requirement; typically, you wouldn't have hardcoded values in a production query.

However, you could write your query like:

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD = '1100' AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD = '1110';
```

You didn't have an operator on the second half of your query (`DEP_CD '1110'`), so I have assumed you wanted `=` as that seems to make the most sense. As such I have changed the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, since DEP_CD is in both the predicate and the list of columns to select.

However, it would be better to change the query to the following, so you're not querying the same table twice:

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD
FROM   EMP
WHERE  DEP_CD = '1110'
OR     (DEP_CD = '1100'
        AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

"Didn't work" is not an Oracle error message. What does it actually mean?

This looks more like pseudocode than real code so it is difficult to guess.

`IF` means  "PL/SQL". If that's so, then `SELECT` requires `INTO`. As you use `UNION`, you can't `SELECT INTO` scalar variables but *something else* (a collection?).

Also, statements should be terminated by semi-colon.

It would probably help if you posted some more info/code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT NM,
       DEP_CD
  FROM EMP
 WHERE DEP_CD = '1110'
       OR ( DEP_CD = '1100'
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                  FROM BBS_TABLE
                 WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100'
                ) 
           );
```